# How to create GraphQL enums from an endpoint?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have an endpoint that I hit, which returns an array of enum values. Is there a way for me to populate an enum in that within my graphql schema?

I couldn't find any info on this when searching. I'm not sure if it's possible because I have to hardcode the enum into my schema string.

I'm using Apollo server.

Comment: If the data is dynamic, e.g. list of tags, then it doesn't really make sense to treat it as an enum. If the endpoint returns some data that's only ever going to be a predefined set of values, like a state (SUCCESS, FAILURE, etc), then it might make sense to define manually this enum in your schema to expose the possible values to the client apps.

Comment: That said, we'd need a [mcve] (or just more info on your use-case) to be able to help.

Comment: @EmileBergeron the Enums are going to be the same, but every few days another could be added.

Comment: Then it's data, not an enum.

Comment: the data that comes back from the endpoint will be an array of strings that i'd like to be mapped to an enum in my graphql schema

Comment: The schema is meant to be constant in time, as a validation tool, if it changes based on data, it's no longer serving its purposes.

Comment: As @EmileBergeron said a schema should be constant, because it is your contract.